# LDAP Authentication in Flask using flask_simpleldap returns "Credentials invalid"

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, flask, ldap

I am trying to use LDAP Authentication in Python Flask.

Here's my test page, taken from SimpleLDAP official documentation:

```
from flask import Flask, g, request, session, redirect, url_for
from flask_simpleldap import LDAP

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'dev key'
app.debug = True

#app.config['LDAP_USE_SSL'] = True
app.config['LDAP_HOST'] = 'my-dc-server'
app.config['LDAP_BASE_DN'] = 'OU=-my-ou,dc=my,dc=domain,dc=com'
app.config['LDAP_USERNAME'] = 'CN=my-domain-admin-working-user,OU=my-ou,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com'
app.config['LDAP_PASSWORD'] = 'my-domain-admin-working-password'

ldap = LDAP(app)

@app.route('/')
@ldap.basic_auth_required
def index():
    return 'Welcome, {0}!'.format(g.ldap_username)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

If I input a working domain user into the popup I always get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/ipcatalogue_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/ipcatalogue_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/ubuntu/ipcatalogue_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/ipcatalogue_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ubuntu/ipcatalogue_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ubuntu/ipcatalogue_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/ubuntu/ipcatalogue_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/ubuntu/ipcatalogue_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ubuntu/ipcatalogue_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ubuntu/ipcatalogue_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/ipcatalogue_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_simpleldap/__init__.py", line 386, in wrapped
    if not self.bind_user(req_username, req_password):
  File "/home/ubuntu/ipcatalogue_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_simpleldap/__init__.py", line 152, in bind_user
    user_dn = self.get_object_details(user=username, dn_only=True)
  File "/home/ubuntu/ipcatalogue_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_simpleldap/__init__.py", line 185, in get_object_details
    conn = self.bind
  File "/home/ubuntu/ipcatalogue_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_simpleldap/__init__.py", line 129, in bind
    raise LDAPException(self.error(e.args))
flask_simpleldap.LDAPException: Invalid credentials
```

Domain user/password have been tested using RDP to my-dc-server and work fine.

I've tried using LDAP_USE_SSL = True or with commenting it (as in example), same result.

What am I missing?

UPDATE:

```
from flask import Flask, g, request, session, redirect, url_for
from flask_simpleldap import LDAP

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'dev key'
app.debug = True

app.config['LDAP_HOST'] = 'my-dc-server'
app.config['LDAP_BASE_DN'] = 'OU=-my-ou,dc=my,dc=domain,dc=com'
app.config['LDAP_USERNAME'] = 'my-domain\\my-domain-admin-working-user'
app.config['LDAP_PASSWORD'] = 'my-domain-admin-working-password'

ldap = LDAP(app)

@app.route('/')
@ldap.basic_auth_required
def index():
    return 'Welcome, {0}!'.format(g.ldap_username)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

With the new code I now obtain:

```
/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_simpleldap/__init__.py", line 201, in get_object_details
raise LDAPException(self.error(e.args))
flask_simpleldap.LDAPException: No such object
```

Comment: Are you using the correct form to specify you credentials? Is there some strange charachter in your password that might need to be escaped?

Comment: Hi @Jonathan
I've super simplified my password.
In the last test I'm using only A-z letters and numbers.
No special characters, nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the username as specified here: [User Name Formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380525(v=vs.85).aspx)

Both formats were working fine for me with your provided code.

Comment: Hi @HelmuthB and thanks for using your time to help.
I've tried logging in as:
user vagrant 
password vagrant - standard superuser for a vagrant machine and also domain admin and it returns me the same error. So I tried domainname\vagrant and same password, same error. If I login to the server using this user / password it works fine. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm super sorry for the confusion. What I meant were the credentials in LDAP:
`app.config['LDAP_USERNAME'] = 'my-domain\\my-domain-admin-working-user'`

Comment: Hi @HelmutB and sorry for the delay. I've just updated my question with new results...